# autocomplete in firestore doesn't work as expected- Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My autocomplete works, but not as expected. I have 2 movie titles:

```
"aaa"
"aaaaa"
```

When I start typing the results filter. The problem is when I'm typing I have to enter **5 as** in order for the first title to disappear instead of 4 since is not a match and **7 as** for the second title to disappear instead of 6, since is not a match.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchValue" (keydown)="search($event)" />
```

**TS**

```
search($event) {
    let param = $event.target.value;
    this.startAt.next(param);
    this.endAt.next(param + "\uf8ff");
    this.movieSearched = this.afs
      .collection("movies", ref =>
        ref
          .orderBy("title")
          .startAt(param)
          .endAt(param + "\uf8ff")
      )
      .valueChanges();
  }
```

I have even tried instead of using `$event.target.value` I used the 2 data-biding variable `searchValue`, but I get the same problem

Comment: An alternative is to use `(ngModelChange)="search($event)"`, where `$event` is the content string.

Comment: Thanks @ConnorsFan that works too! I just learned something new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure that the autocomplete works when modifying the input content by any means (typing, cutting, pasting), handle the `ngModelChange` event:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchValue" (ngModelChange)="search($event)" />
```

where `$event` is the input element content:

```
search(param: string) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I found the solution by using `keyup`.If anyone has a better solution, by all means post it and get your points :)

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchValue" (keyup)="search($event)" />
```